# Retrieve taxonomy terms in order of their post's date?

Tags: taxonomy, order, date

I'm building out a custom taxonomy archive page that needs to list terms in order by their associated post's `post_date`. I wrote this, it's working, but I hate resorting to custom SQL:

```
global $wpdb;

$post_types = array( 'series' );
$taxonomy   = array( 'taxonomy' );
$order      = 'DESC';

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT t.*
    FROM $wpdb->terms AS t
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt
        ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr
        ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p
        ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ( '" . implode( "','", $taxonomy ) . "' )
    AND p.post_type IN ( '" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "' )
    ORDER BY p.post_date {$order};";

$terms_ordered_by_post_date = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Curious if anyone has a better solution?

Comment: "list terms in order by their associated post's `post_date`" - what if a term is applied to more than one post? Which post's `post_date` should matter?

Comment: Awesome question! Setting `DISTINCT` means that the terms will be unique and ordered by the associated post_date. **Edit** original explanation was terrible, updated.

Comment: I've submitted a core patch to see what feedback that might garner https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28439

Comment: I say ballpark, for anything at this level of logic you are usually doomed to custom SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`terms_clauses`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1533) filter, and then just use `get_terms()`:

```
function wpse147412_order_terms_by_post_date( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( 'post_date' !== $args['orderby'] ) {
        return $pieces;
    }

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array( 'post_types' => 'post' ) );

    $pieces['fields']   = 'DISTINCT ' . $pieces['fields'];
    $pieces['join']    .= " JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id";
    $pieces['join']    .= " JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID = tr.object_id";
    $pieces['where']   .= " AND p.post_type IN ('" . implode( "', '", (array) $args['post_types'] ) . "')";
    $pieces['orderby']  = 'ORDER BY p.post_date';

    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', 'wpse147412_order_terms_by_post_date', 10, 3 );

....

$terms = get_terms( 'taxonomy', array( 'post_types' => 'series', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Comment: This is great, I'm going to switch my implementation to something that's filter based. Thank you!